# Custom validations on textbox

Tags: c#, validation

How to code NAME textbox that accepts only letters & blankspaces. Same for NUMBER textbox:

```
private void tbOwnerName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Characters only");

    }*/
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation textbox in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866314/validation-textbox-in-winforms)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForm UI Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769184/winform-ui-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do that is using regular expressions , in C# you can use REGEX class to check if an string matches a patterns that declared by regular expression.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$");
Match match = regex.Match("Dot 55 Perls");
if (match.Success)
{
    //do something
}
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words) answer might help you to find the proper regular expression for your situation.

Comment: Better to add some sample code, otherwise it will be considered as a low quality answer.

Comment: I know that but i posted answer from my smart phone , and it was hard to add sample code